# ant can not incremental build

Tags: java, ant

I am using Ant to build a java project, but I have some problem enabling incremental build in Ant.

My build.xml is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="fax" basedir="." default="build">
   <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
   <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>

   <target name="build" description="Compile source">
      <javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}"></javac>
   </target>
</project>
```

But if I run 'ant build' for multiple times, the source files will be compiled multiple times. It seems the incremental build does not help.

However if I change my build.xml to this, remove the build directory and build directly in source directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="fax" basedir="." default="build">
   <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>

   <target name="build" description="Compile source">
      <javac srcdir="${src.dir}"></javac>
   </target>
</project>
```

Using this build.xml I can see the result of incremental build. When I run 'ant build' for multiple times, the source files are compiled only in the first run.

I wonder why this happens and how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ant -debug` you will see additional output that may give a clue, for instance

```
[javac] foo.java added as foo.class doesn't exist.
```

This means that it will rebuild `foo.java`, because the corresponding class file doesn't exist yet. So it is in fact operating in incremental mode.

At some point I had the same issue as you describe. It turned out that the value of my `srcdir` property was incorrect: it was `c:\....\java` while it had to be `c:\....\java\src`. For some reason ant didn't complain, the class files were correctly written to `destdir`, but the "incremental" feature was broken due to this fact.

Answer (score -1):

`javac` will compile a Java source tree.

Javac will look for the all Java source files in the source and destination directory. It will compile only those java files for which there is no .class present or where the class file is older than the .java file.
This is an incremental approach. Just compile missing and updated files.

for more information you can refer [javac](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) documentation.